# Redirect whole subfolder to a handler

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder which is in a subfolder from my www directory

like

www/somesub

there i put a htaccess file which has the following rewrite rule in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule ^ajax/(.+?)/(\w+)/(\w+?)$ /ajax/handler.php?any=$1&idea=$2&lol=$3 [L]
```

This should redirect all calls from its sub directory ajax to the handler which is inside... sadly this dous not work... anyone any idea why?

examlple would be:
from

```
domain/somesub/ajax/some/notsoawsome/code
```

to

```
domain/somesub/ajax/handler?any=some&idea=notsoawsome&lol=code
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Does it work without the leading caret?

Comment: you mean without ^, nope dous not work

Comment: tried it any way i know of. the god damn thing dous not work. I checked to see if rewrite is on... it is on.... and it isgrumpy ~~

Comment: RewriteLog enabled? Does it say anything? Lowered the RewriteLogLevel? What do you see instead of the intended result: 500 or 404?

Comment: i see a 404 response from server when i type the link, log is enabled. will read it now.

Comment: The RewriteRule itself seems fine, although I wouldn't use the question marks within the parentheses they shouldn't interfere. As such it has to be something about the locations of the folder or the specifics of the execution. 404 either means the rule does nlt match, or its rewritten result doesn't exist. The log should show all this.

Comment: in the log which i had to reset... was 1.9GB big! on my local machine :) now it says it gous on the original adress. The rule dous not get applied Q_Q

Comment: Make an obvious typo to ensure the htaccess is even parsed, it should return a 500 error.

Comment: Well it gets down to basic debugging then - reduce the RewriteRule to its bare metal basics, and when it works start making it more complicated again until it stops. Just return it to a single parameter and see where it ends :)